# how Could I connect one column QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to connect only one column when changing its value by the user, because if you use

`self.Table.cellChanged()`
it will send a signal if all values ​​are changed from the database

Example(Look to #Comment to down)

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class SalesMan(object):

    def __init__(self, window):
        window.resize(650, 600)
        window.setWindowTitle('Example')
        self.Window = window
        self.Barcode = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(window)
        self.Table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(100, 6, window)
        self.Table.setGeometry(0, 0, 650, 600)
        self.Table.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.Table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        # need Call if column(0,1) Changed, Not All Column
        self.Table.cellChanged.connect(self.Ex)

    def Ex(self):
        print('Some')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    d = SalesMan(form)
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your slot will have to parameters: row and column. You should handle only those calls, where the column number is what you expect and ignore all others.

Comment: it is great, but how can i do it

Comment: Let' say, you need changes for only the first column. In the slot you write: `if (column == 0) { do something } else { return; }`.

Comment: i'm sorry but I don't know how to do that

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Ok Done, Look to post

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is filter the column based on the parameters transmitted through the signal:

```
class SalesMan(object):
    def __init__(self, window):
        window.resize(650, 600)
        window.setWindowTitle("Example")
        self.Window = window
        self.Barcode = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(window)
        self.Table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(100, 6, window)
        self.Table.setGeometry(0, 0, 650, 600)
        self.Table.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.Table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        # need Call if column(0,1) Changed, Not All Column
        self.Table.cellChanged.connect(self.Ex)

    def Ex(self, row, column):
        if column == 0:
            print("Some", row, column)
```